# change ImageVIew by Capture

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview, crop, android-camera-intent

here the question I want Change Imageview named  cameraView

I use `startActivityforResult` But it doens't work.

I already write permissions it needs.

ImageView doens't change

my whole code is 
http://pastie.org/5340010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your trying to change the view to the image captured from the Camera why not directly set it to the ImageView in the onActivityResult ?

have a look at the following piece of code :

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bm=(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Dont know if this helped, but it will work for sure !